# Automatically turn on monitor at certain time

Tags: gnome, power-management, monitor, display-manager

When I lock my session, the monitor turns off after a while. How do I set it up so that the monitor are scheduled at a certain time (i.e at 8 am) to turn on to show the lock screen ?

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xset` in conjunction with `cron` to manage `dpms` (Display power management system), something like this:

```
00 08 * * *   DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on
```

In your crontab file (`crontab -e`) would force your monitor to be awake at 8 AM.